# The restful api is always in pending state, and tomcat occurs excpetion

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have a web application, But I meet a problem. The request is always in **pending** state sometimes, but it works fine some other time. It is an **accident**, just like the following picture:
[image]

Tomcat will does not work any more after it occurs "pending state", then I need to restart tomcat, and anything is okay. I can find exception in log files: `catalina.2017-03-05.log`,`localhost.2017-03-05.log`:
**In file `catalina.2017-03-05.log`:**

```
    05-Mar-2017 13:29:55.187 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [EducationCloud-Restful] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
(...)
05-Mar-2017 13:29:55.254 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:389)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Mar-2017 13:29:55.274 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest Error finishing response
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.commit(Http11OutputBuffer.java:351)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest(Http11Processor.java:1786)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1149)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**In file `localhost.2017-03-05.log':**

```
05-Mar-2017 13:29:55.253 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke Exception Processing null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:236)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Who can help me to tell me what happend please? Thank you so much!

Related:
Tomcat v8.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem, the reason is from dbcp2, Its default max connections number is 8, so all the request will be in pending state when connection reached 8. The way to solve this problem is that we can set the max total and remove the connections when it become unuseful,Just like below:

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource()
dataSource.setMaxTotal(-1);  
dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedOnBorrow(true);
dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(5);
```

The negative number(-1) means no limit, and the "5" means 5 seconds.